# Declare Terraform Variable: Error all map elements must have the same type

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have declared variable

```
variable subnets{
    type = map(any)
}
```

with values

```
subnets = {
    subnet1 = {
        name    =   "subnet1"
        address_prefixes=   ["10.0.0.0/24"]
        delegation = {}
    },
    subnet2 = {
        name    =   "subnet2"
        address_prefixes=   ["10.0.1.0/24"]
        delegation = {}
    },
        subnet3 = {
        name    =   "subnet3"
        address_prefixes=   ["10.0.2.0/24"]
        delegation = {
            name = "delegation1"
            service_delegation = {
                name = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
                
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

but getting error:The given value is not suitable for var.subnets all map elements must have the same type. because i have delegation block in only one of them

correct way to declare this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to Declare Terraform Variable which in general showsup an Error all map elements must have the same type but I able to provision your requirement successfully.

In general, when you define a map variable type in terraform all elements of the map must have the same type. This means that each element in your `subnets` map must have the same structure. The blocker you're encountering is because `subnet1` and `subnet2` have an empty `delegation` block, while `subnet3` has a populated `delegation` block.

To fix this issue, you can define a more detailed structure for your `subnets` variable. One approach is to use `object` type with optional attributes for the `delegation` block

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}


# Variable Definition
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name              = string
    address_prefixes  = list(string)
    delegation = object({
      name               = string
      service_delegation = object({
        name = string
      })
    })
  }))
  default = {
    subnet1 = {
      name              = "subnet1"
      address_prefixes  = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
      delegation        = null
    },
    subnet2 = {
      name              = "subnet2"
      address_prefixes  = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
      delegation        = null
    },
    subnet3 = {
      name              = "subnet3"
      address_prefixes  = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
      delegation        = {
        name = "delegation1"
        service_delegation = {
          name = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Create a Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

# Create a Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demovnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"] # This should cover all the subnets
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Create Subnets
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = each.value.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes

  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = each.value.delegation != null ? [each.value.delegation] : []
    content {
      name = delegation.value.name
      service_delegation {
        name = delegation.value.service_delegation.name
        actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was running into a similar issue. Opting to rather define the map as a list of objects was a much better solution.